# android sha512 example

Tags: java, android, performance, sha512

1. Can someone provide an example for java/android on how to hash a password using `PW_HASH_ITERATION_COUNT` iterations of sha512 + salt?

   in pseudo code:

   ```
   hash = sha512(concat(pw,salt));
   for (i = 1; i<PW_HASH_ITERATION_COUNT; i++){
       hash = sha512(concat(hash,concat(pw,salt)));
   }
   ```

   Where `z = concat(x,y)` is the concatenation of x and y.

   Maybe using [MessageDigest](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/security/MessageDigest.html) ?
2. What would you suggest as `PW_HASH_ITERATION_COUNT`? How many iterations would be the maximum so that this might even run on some older devices (2.1+)

**UPDATE UPDATE UPDATE**

Due to good reasons, we will use [bcrypt](http://codahale.com/how-to-safely-store-a-password/) to encrypt our passwords. We use the [jBCrypt](http://www.mindrot.org/projects/jBCrypt/) implementation.

Anyway.. to answer the question... this is the code for the question above to use SHA-512 with the MessageDigest:

```
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import de.seduceme.utils.Base64;

public class PwStorage {
    public static int PW_HASH_ITERATION_COUNT = 5000;
    private static MessageDigest md;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String pw = "teüöäßÖst1";
        String salt = "e33ptcbnto8wo8c4o48kwws0g8ksck0";

        try {
            md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-512");
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new RuntimeException("No Such Algorithm");
        }

        String result = PwStorage.hashPw(pw, salt);
        System.out.println(result);
        // result: 2SzT+ikuO9FBq7KJWulZy2uZYujLjFkSpcOwlfBhi6VvajJMr6gxuRo5WvilrMlcM/44u2q8Y1smUlidZQrLCQ==
    }


    private static String hashPw(String pw, String salt) {
        byte[] bSalt;
        byte[] bPw;

        try {
            bSalt = salt.getBytes("UTF-8");
            bPw = pw.getBytes("UTF-8");
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Unsupported Encoding", e);
        }

        byte[] digest = run(bPw, bSalt);
        for (int i = 0; i < PW_HASH_ITERATION_COUNT - 1; i++) {
            digest = run(digest, bSalt);
        }

        return Base64.encodeBytes(digest);
    }

    private static byte[] run(byte[] input, byte[] salt) {
        md.update(input);
        return md.digest(salt);
    }
}
```

With [this Base64 lib](http://iharder.net/base64).

Comment: Please answer your own question, as an actual answer. This is not a forum, but a Q&A format.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read [my post](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/51403/what-should-web-programmers-know-about-cryptography/51528#51528) here, especially the post I linked to about [password hashing](http://chargen.matasano.com/chargen/2007/9/7/enough-with-the-rainbow-tables-what-you-need-to-know-about-s.html).

- You should ideally use bcrypt or scrypt rather than doing your own password hashing.
- But if you must, you should run for a few thousand iterations at the minimum, preferably more.

Yes, you can use `MessageDigest` for SHA-512. Each time you call `digest`, the state of the object automatically resets, which is really handy---you can start updating for the next iteration straight away.

But I still think you should use bcrypt or scrypt instead. For your own good, and the good of your users. :-)

Comment: do you know a correct implementation of bcrypt for java (android)? and maybe for objectiv-c (ios), too?

Comment: @Stuck: For Java, I use Damien Miller's implementation, [jBCrypt](http://www.mindrot.org/projects/jBCrypt/). Damien is the maintainer of portable OpenSSH and I trust his security knowledge. Not sure about Objective-C.

Answer (score 0):

a [HMAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hmac) is found to be sufficient for what you wanna do and it does only 2 iterations

it boils down to

```
hash = sha512(concat(xor(salt,nonce2),sha512(concat(xor(salt,nonce1),pw)));
```

Comment: HMAC is still too fast for password hashing. Please read the article linked to in my post, as to why you need a few thousand iterations. The point is to make the password _slow_ to crack, by making each password trial take a long time (e.g., a quarter of a second each). People legitimately logging on the site won't "feel" a quarter of a second; but people cracking passwords _will_ feel those quarter seconds, painfully, as they're trying to attempt a billion passwords.