# How to create a SHA-512 hash?

Tags: java, android, hash, sha

I am trying to create a SHA-512 or SHA-256 system within my Java code, to store passwords. I have looked around and can't find any working code. Does anyone have an idea where to start? Or is there a plugin that hashes strings for me?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [android sha512 example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6393292/android-sha512-example)

Comment: [Jasypt: How to encrypt user passwords](http://www.jasypt.org/howtoencryptuserpasswords.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;

public String get_SHA_512_SecurePassword(String passwordToHash, String              salt){
String generatedPassword = null;
try {
     MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-512");
     md.update(salt.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
     byte[] bytes = md.digest(passwordToHash.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
     StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
     for(int i=0; i< bytes.length ;i++){
        sb.append(Integer.toString((bytes[i] & 0xff) + 0x100, 16).substring(1));
     }
     generatedPassword = sb.toString();
    } 
   catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
   }
return generatedPassword;
}
```